# formula to match on multiple values and then mapping to another value in another column

Tags: powerbi, max, grouping, min

currently my cases are either approved or denied. sometimes if they are approved and denied on the same day, then the denied maps to partially denied.
this is sample data

[image]

in power bi, i am trying to do this with grouping but whats happening is that it does this

[image]

the problem is that i am now missing the approved line and therefore my approved counts are much lower than they are.  if the case was approved..i still want to count that. but the denial changes to partial denial.

I tried to group it and see if one case has two different decisions then i can have the output to be partial denial. but i didnt realize that this would then remove my approved case altogether and my count of approved are lower than they should be.

how do i do my mapping without grouping? because the case # and the date has to be the same and they are in different rows.